# How to POST a json using FromBody

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, How can I post to a controller and receive the JObject directly?
The error I am getting is

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Save([System.Web.Http.FromBody] JObject result)
    {

    }
}
```

Client:

```
<script>
    function doIt() {
        var request = {
            data: {
                property1: "test1",
                property2: "test2"
            }
        };

        $.post("/Home/Save", request);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ....why do you want to do this? Why not create a class to represent the data that you expect to post to this endpoint?

Comment: @mason I don't need that, the data goes to the db. I only need to modify parts of it before saving it to the db.

Comment: Of course you don't *need it*. But it will make all this easier. Is there anything that would prevent you from doing so?

Comment: @DonBox so you just need to know how to post data to the controller or does it have to be with `FromBody`? The approach doesn't matter? If data is going to the db anyway, why would you need JObject?

Comment: @Pirate I just need to know what's wrong why it doesn't work. I found several places where this should work fine but it doesn't, I'm getting that error I mentioned

Comment: try to stringify your object before doing post

Comment: @DonBox exactly what line does it throw an exception. Right at `[System.Web.Http.FromBody] JObject result` when it hits the action?

Comment: That article is using ASP.NET MVC Core. You've mentioned you're using ASP.NET MVC 4. Those are different versions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The article says how it is in ASP.NET MVC Core too. That's what I am interested about.

Comment: You say ASP.NET 4.8, but you are showing ASP.NET Core code... These are two completely different frameworks that do things completely different. The article you reference shows ASP.NET Core. Which is it?

Comment: There appears to be some confusion around exactly what versions of things you are using. You stated "I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.8". ASP.NET MVC 4.8 isn't a thing! Are you using ASP.Net MVC 5 on .Net Framework 4.8? The article is purely about ASP.Net Core 3.0

Comment: @phuzi The article says "Now, the model binder in MVC/WebApi is quite annoying, in that the following code doesn’t work when you POST a JSON object to an API. ...." and then he says "in order for this to work, you have to create the object to POST like this:" and gives the example

Comment: With some luck maybe someone will really answer my question. Or not.

Comment: You will not get an answer, and this question should be closed. You are still mixing two frameworks. This is an invalid question and will not yield a valid answer.

Comment: Where do you see I am mixing frameworks? As far as I see you don't bother reading the whole question

Comment: @DonBox Where in the article does it mention how to do it in .NET Framework? And you have yet to answer my question about why you can't simply define a class to represent your data.

Comment: @DonBox MVC/WebAPI are still around in .Net Core it's just that they come under ASP.Net Core and not separate as they did with the .Net Framework versions where you have ASP.Net MVC and ASP.Net WebAPI. The article you linked to is pure .Net Core, there is no mention of .Net Framework.

Comment: @phuzi few comments below I already said clearly that the author mentions ASP.NET MVC and where exactly

Comment: There you go, I removed the link to the article so there's no discussion around that.